# Name age does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, scope, calculator

I have an assignment to write a simple program in C# on Visual Studio that reads your birth date from the console, prints back your age now and your age after ten years.

I've found a Microsoft tutorial and decided to use it but it went wrong. Here's the tutorial: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Twenty-C-Questions-Explained/14

I'm not done with the task and I see the following errors: `'The name age does not exist in the current context'`.

```
namespace AgeAfterTenYears
{
    class AgeAfterTenYears
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter birthdate - DD/MM/YYYY");
            string birthdate = Console.ReadLine();
            DateTime bd = Convert.ToDateTime(birthdate);
            DateTime curDate = DateTime.Today;
            if (bd > curDate)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Birthdate must be equal to or before today");
            }
            else
            {
                int age = curDate.Year - bd.Year;
            }

            if (bd.Month > curDate.Month)
            {
                age--;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("You are: {0} years old", age);
        }
    }
}
```

I've found different solutions for the task but I'd really like to understand what's wrong with mine. Probably it's something stupid but I'm doing this after the first lesson so...

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    using System;

    namespace AgeAfterTenYears
    {
    class AgeAfterTenYears
    {
    static void Main()
    {
        var age = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter birthdate - DD/MM/YYYY");
        string birthdate = Console.ReadLine();
        DateTime bd = Convert.ToDateTime(birthdate);
        DateTime curDate = DateTime.Today;
        if (bd > curDate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Birthdate must be equal to or before today");
        }
        else
        {
            age = curDate.Year - bd.Year;
        }
        if (bd.Month > curDate.Month)
        {
           age = --set your age here//curDate.Year - bd.Year
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You are: {0} years old", age);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but got another error: 'A local variable named 'age' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'age', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else'. I don't know why it went wrong.

Comment: impossible perhaps you have age declared in two places

Comment: The whole code is written in the description of my problem. Now I've just added var age = 0; in the beginning.

Comment: you are not understanding what the word `Scope` means you can not see age when outside of the if statement declare it outside of the conditional statement

Comment: I have declared it like you said but in the else statement I had left it 'int age = curDate.Year - bd.Year;' when it should be just 'age = curDate.Year - bd.Year;'. 
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `age` in the `else` statement:

```
else
{
    int age = curDate.Year - bd.Year;
}
```

This means that the code outside that else statement cannot "see" the variable `age`. It is out of scope.

You should move the variable declaration above the first `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should modify your `else` part as follows:

```
else
{
    int age = curDate.Year - bd.Year;
    if (bd.Month > curDate.Month)
    {
        age--;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("You are: {0} years old", age);
}
```

Comment: Lots of similar answers, but this is the first one I saw that wouldn't continue on with the month comparison for an invalid birthdate.

Answer (score 0):

`age` does not exists here:

```
if (bd.Month > curDate.Month)
{
    age--;
}
```

`int age` should be declared out of `if-else` if you want to access it.

```
int age = 0;

if (bd > curDate)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Birthdate must be equal to or before today");
}
else
{
    age = curDate.Year - bd.Year;
}

if (bd.Month > curDate.Month)
{
    age--;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've tried it but now I get a different error: 'A local variable named 'age' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'age', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else'.

Answer (score 0):

Move `age` outside the `else` block and assign it a default value :

```
int age = 0;

if(...)
{
...
}
else
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `age` is declared only in `else` block and you try to use it in next `if` block, where isn't declared.