# Creating an int inside an if/else and using it later

Tags: c#, if-statement, scope

I'm playing with stuff here and am having trouble with something.

I have an input; it can be either a number or a letter.  I have to check whether it's a number or a letter. So I used an `if` for that.  If the input is a number, my code should create an int.  If it's a letter, it should create a different int.  But I can't use the integer later on for some reason.  Any way to solve that?

```
Console.WriteLine("Length (ms)");
string I = Console.ReadLine();
int I2 = Int32.Parse(I);
Console.WriteLine("Height: r for random");
string L = Console.ReadLine();
//So it asks for an input,for which I here want to check what it is
if (L != "r")
{
    int He = Int32.Parse(L);
}
else
{
    Random Hi = new Random();
    int He = Hi.Next(1, 50);
}
//----------------------I want to use the ints in here
while(true)
{
    Random R = new Random();
    Random R2 = new Random();
    int H = R2.Next(1,He);
    int rH = H * 100;
    Console.WriteLine("Height is {0}",H);
    Console.Beep(rH,I2);
```

Comment: Define it earlier in the preceeding scope.

Comment: Declare `int He;` outside of the if statement and then just assign values inside the statement. The keyword to search for on this issue is "scope". The scope of a declared parameter is basically the innermost block it is declared in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Name age does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092403/name-age-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the scope of `int He` to take it outside of the conditional blocks.

```
int He;
if (L != "r")
{
     He = Int32.Parse(L);
}
else
{
     Random Hi = new Random();
     He = Hi.Next(1, 50);
}
```

You could also use the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) in this example to make the code look like which might be preferable as a matter of style.

```
int He = L != "r" ? Int32.Parse(L) : (new Random()).Next(1, 50);
```

One thing that is notable, about both the above, versions is that `Int32.Parse` could raise a number of exceptions based on the format of the `string L` which you probably want to handle either using [try - catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) statements or by using the [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method